# how to merge two dataframes and replacing the column with same name with other column in R

Tags: r

I have following two dataframes in R

```
df1
key      volume     name      hours      location
ABC       456       SS32      34.34       London
ERT       34        SS31      33.14       London
TYU       21        SS33      3           London
GHU       678       SS35      1.30        London
THU       67        SS35      0.30        London

df2
key      volume     hours      
ABC       345       37.34       
ERT       54        31.14       
TYU       12        6.23           
GHU       679       0.50
```

Now I want to merge this two dataframes replacing columns `volume and hours`in `df1` with columns from `df2` 
and where there is no match on `key` column, keep the original data from `df1`

My desired dataframe would be

```
df1
key      volume     name      hours      location
ABC       345       SS32      37.34       London
ERT       54        SS31      31.14       London
TYU       12        SS33      6.23        London
GHU       679       SS35      0.50        London
THU       67        SS35      0.30        London
```

When I do a left join it creates a `volume.1` and `hours.1` as two new variables

Comment: can you add the code you are using to do a left join?  It will be easier for others to suggest answers if they can see and run all of your relevant code

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I thought you could approach this:

**Join then overwrite**
I can get the result by joining and then overwriting `df1` with the values from `df2`. But this solution feels very clunky.

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = "key", suffix = c("", ".2")) %>%
  mutate(volume = if_else(is.na(volume.2), volume, volume.2),
         hours = if_else(is.na(hours.2), hours, hours.2)) %>%
  select(-volume.2, -hours.2)

#>   key volume name hours location
#> 1 ABC    345 SS32 37.34   London
#> 2 ERT     54 SS31 31.14   London
#> 3 TYU     12 SS33  6.23   London
#> 4 GHU    679 SS35  0.50   London
#> 5 THU     67 SS35  0.30   London
```

**Bind rows**
An alternative approach could be to `bind_rows` instead and keep the `first` values from `df1` for name and location and the `last` values for volume and hours which will be equal to values from `df2` (if available). This feels "neater" to me than joining and overwriting.

```r
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(name     = first(name),                                         
            location = first(location),
            volume   = last(volume),
            hours    = last(hours))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>     key  name location volume hours
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1   ABC  SS32   London    345 37.34
#> 2   ERT  SS31   London     54 31.14
#> 3   GHU  SS35   London    679  0.50
#> 4   THU  SS35   London     67  0.30
#> 5   TYU  SS33   London     12  6.23
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
df3 <- inner_join(df1[c("key", "name", "location")], df2, by = "key") %>%
       bind_rows(anti_join(df1, df2, by = "key") ) %>% 
       select(key, volume, name, hours, location)
```